# System.Forms.SaveFileDialog's OverwritePrompt not translated

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using System.Forms.SaveFileDialog . My native language in my OS is japanese. When saving an existing file the overwriteprompt states "xxx already exists,Do you want to replace it?" , shouldn't it be in japanese and not in english, since system locale is in japanese? Arigato..

Comment: Im working on a .NET framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SaveFileDialog class is a thin wrapper around a dialog implemented by the operating system.  You'll see the exact same one in, say, Notepad.  The warning message is displayed by that dialog, not .NET code.  IFileDialog::SetOptions() method, FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT option.  It is enabled by default.

So you need to look at your operating system config for the problem.  Like an English version of Windows, switched to Japanese as the default language.  Which gets programs that support Japanese localization to display Japanese, including .NET, but leaves all OS dialogs in English.  Or having the Ultimate edition with both English and Japanese language packs installed and some code switching the Thread.CurrentCulture to English.  If not your code then a misbehaving shell extension could do that.

Comment: I think its most likely be a misbehaving shell, since the OS itself is native japanese. ill be sure to look on it more. Ill be sure to give a feedback tomorrow. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: After days of research i found out that you would still need to install .NET Framework language pack that correspond to your Native language the link can be found here. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23067